# Adding multiple dictionaries of list based on semi column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the data

```
data = [{'name': 'Dave', 'role': 'Manager'}, {'name': 'David', 'role': 'Engineer'}]
```

I am intending to add the values based on same keys and merging it by semicolon.
Expected output is like this as follows

```
{'name': 'Dave;David', 'role': 'Manager;Engineer'}
```

What I am trying to do is to convert into matrix then adding all the elements based on the index but it is very tedious approach.

```
result = [[i[e] for e in sorted(i.keys())] for i in data]
print(result)
```

```
current output: [['Dave', 'Manager'], ['David', 'Engineer']]
```

Comment: `'Dave;David'` is a string which results from the concatenation of the two names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want, assuming that data always contains dictionaries of strings.

I'm checking if each dictionary key already exists in the final dictionary. If it doesn't I add it, if it does I append it to the current value using the semicolon as a separator.

```
data = [{'name': 'Dave', 'role': 'Manager'}, {'name': 'David', 'role': 'Engineer'}]

final = {}
for dict in data:
    for k,v in dict.items():
        if k in final:
            final[k] += ';' + v
        else:
            final[k] = v

print(final)
```